# Javascript Array.prototype.map function with instance methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if it was possible to pass an instance method into the Array.prototype.map function.

for example, I basically want this functionality without having to make a separate function

```js
function Node(n) {
  this.val = n;
}
Node.prototype.isBig = function() {
  return this.val > 5;
}

var myArray = [
  new Node(1), new Node(2), new Node(3),
  new Node(7), new Node(8), new Node(9)
];

console.log(myArray);

var result = myArray.map(function(node) {
  return node.isBig();
});

console.log(result);
```

in java I would be able to do `.map(Node::isBig)`. Can I do something to change the map parameter so that I don't have to create a function?

I am also open to solutions with lodash if you cannot do it with vanilla js.

Comment: As you can see from Oriol's answer, it can be done, but it's almost as verbose as the anonymous function, and IMHO it's not as clear.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it strictly without creating new functions, but you can avoid function expressions and declarations by [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) existing functions to some value.

For example, you can use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call `Node.prototype.isBig` with the appropriate `this` value.

```
var result = myArray.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(Node.prototype.isBig));
```

There is also a proposal of a [bind operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator), which I think it would allow

```
var result = myArray.map(::Node.prototype.isBig.call);
```

Note additional arguments (index and array) will be passed to the `isBig` method.

```js
function Node(n) {
  this.val = n;
}
Node.prototype.isBig = function() {
  return this.val > 5;
};
var myArray = [
  new Node(1), new Node(2), new Node(3),
  new Node(7), new Node(8), new Node(9)
];
var result = myArray.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(Node.prototype.isBig));
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

And in ES6, you can consider using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions):

```
var result = myArray.map(node => node.isBig());
```

Comment: This is really cool, but I have been using JavaScript for 15 years and I always have to read lines like those a few times

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, and I have to test it before posting because I'm not sure if I have thought it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a function that takes node as its parameter (that is, it doesn't rely on `this`

```
Node.isBig = function(node) {
  return node.isBig();
};

//works because function doesn't depend on this
myArray.map(Node.isBig);
// doesn't work, depends on this
myArray.map(Node.prototype.isBig);
```

Alternatively, you could create a function that returns another function that takes its first parameter and calls it as `this`

```
 function passFirstArgAsThis (fun) {
     return function() {
         fun.apply(arguments[0], arguments);
     }
 }
 myArray.map( passFirstArgAsThis(Node.prototype.isBig));
```

A slightly more cryptic implementation is

```
function passFirstArgAsThis(fn) {
    return function() {
        return fn.call.apply(fn, arguments);  
    };
}
```

The equivalent in ES6 is more readable

```
function passFirstArgAsThis(fn) {
    return function() {
        // arguments[0] will be the first argument passed to call
        // map will pass it as the node, we will make it become `this`
        // when calling the passed in function
        return fn.call(...arguments); 
    };
}
```

Understanding that, [Oriol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228772/227299) becomes easier to comprehend

```
function passFirstArgAsThis(fn) {
    // we return a bound function that will execute the call method, bound
    // to the same passed in function 
    return fn.call.bind(fn);
    // Same as 
    // return function() {
    //    return fn.call(...arguments);
    // }
}
```

Personally, I would use fat arrow functions for readability, and not needing an extra "static" function.

```
nodes.map(n=>n.isBig())
```

Comment: I was about to suggest your `Node.isBig` recommendation, but you beat me to it.

Comment: But as you mentioned in the comments, I would just use the anonymous function for clarity

Comment: I wrote that before I thought of defining it as a "static" method. If I needed to do it from multiple places I would use `Node.isBig`.