# Does JavaScript allow replacing lambda with "method references"? If not, why not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lambda, functional-programming

I jump between Java and Javascript a lot at work. I also write a lot of functional code, i.e. chains of lambdas.

One thing I like about Java is I can replace a lambda with a method reference. For example, I can replace this code

```
List<String> trimmedStrings = List.of("hi ", "bye ").stream()
  .map(original -> original.trim())
  .collect(toList());
```

with this:

```
List<String> trimmedStrings = List.of("hi ", "bye ").stream()
  .map(String::trim)
  .collect(toList());
```

I often make this replacement because I'm usually happier with the end state of how the code looks.

I have been wondering if I can do this with Javascript. I just tested this code in my browser console:

```
["hi ", "bye "].map(original => original.trim());
```

first I tried replacing it the simple way, which worked but doesn't accomplish my goal:

```
["hi ", "bye "].map(original => String.prototype.trim.apply(original))
```

So I figured the following would work, but it didn't:

```
["hi ", "bye "].map(String.prototype.trim.apply)
```

it gave me an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Can't call method on  undefined` (in Firefox).

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. Is there another, better way to do what I want here?

Comment: also [Javascript Array.prototype.map function with instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228710/javascript-array-prototype-map-function-with-instance-methods)

Comment: Also keep in mind the possible pitfalls of optional parameters as seen in [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.trim` is just a function. When you call `"foo".trim()` you call that function *and* set `"foo"` as the context. This is just how methods work in JavaScript. I might suggest a `method` helper to get around this -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(method("".trim)))
```

Another option is to define `trim` in advance -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)
   
const trim = method("".trim)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim))
```

```js
[
  "alice",
  "bob",
  "charlie"
]
```

Some methods take additional arguments. `method` works with that too -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)
   
const trim = method("".trim)
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(v => replace(v, "e", "E")))
```

```js
[
  "alicE",
  "bob",
  "charliE"
]
```

You can rewrite `method` to enable [**tacit programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) (aka point-free style) -

```js
const method = f => (...args) => data =>
  f.apply(data, args)
   
const trim = method("".trim)()
const upper = method("".toUpperCase)()
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(replace(/[aeiou]/g, upper)))
```

```js
[
  "AlIcE",
  "bOb",
  "chArlIE"
]
```

Finally we can make `method` smarter to analyze `f.length` to determine if more arguments should be supplied by the caller -

```js
const method = f => 
  f.length == 0
    ? data => f.call(data)
    : (...args) => data => f.apply(data, args)
   
const trim = method("".trim)
const upper = method("".toUpperCase)
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(replace(/[aeiou]/g, upper)))
```

```js
[
  "AlIcE",
  "bOb",
  "chArlIE"
]
```

Comment: This is all covered in the duplicate except for your final curried example.

Comment: sorry pilchard, wasn't aware of the duplicate before answering

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `this` context needs to be set to the string. You can use `Function#call` to execute a function with a particular `this` value.

With just `String.prototype.trim.call`, the `this` context for `Function#call` is not set at the time is called, so you need to use `bind` to keep it.

```js
let res = ["hi ", "bye "].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim));
console.log(res);
// or to make it a bit shorter:
console.log(["hi ", "bye "].map("".trim.call.bind("".trim)));
```

Comment: nice! appreciate the shorter version too!